# How to implement CYK parsing algorithm in Ruby?

Tags: ruby, parsing, dynamic-programming, context-free-grammar, cyk

I am trying to implement CYK algorithm in Ruby according to [pseudocode from Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CYK_algorithm). My implementation fails to produce the correct parse table. In the method given below, `grammar` is a member of my own grammar class. Here is the code:

```
# checks whether a grammar accepts given string
# assumes input grammar to be in CNF

def self.parse(grammar, string)
    n = string.length
    r = grammar.nonterminals.size
    # create n x n x r matrix
    tbl = Array.new(n) { |_| Array.new(n) { |_| Array.new(r, false) } }
    (0...n).each { |s| 
        grammar.rules.each { |rule| 
            # check if rule is unit production: A -> b
            next unless rule.rhs.size == 1
            unit_terminal = rule.rhs[0]
            if unit_terminal.value == string[s]
                v = grammar.nonterminals.index(rule.lhs)
                tbl[0][s][v] = true
            end
        }
    }
    (1...n).each { |l| 
        (0...n - l + 1).each { |s| 
            (0..l - 1).each { |p| 
                # enumerate over A -> B C rules, where A, B and C are
                # indices in array of NTs
                grammar.rules.each { |rule| 
                    next unless rule.rhs.size == 2
                    a = grammar.nonterminals.index(rule.lhs)
                    b = grammar.nonterminals.index(rule.rhs[0])
                    c = grammar.nonterminals.index(rule.rhs[1])
                    if tbl[p][s][b] and tbl[l - p][s + p][c]
                        tbl[l][s][a] = true
                    end
                }
            }
        }
    }
    v = grammar.nonterminals.index(grammar.start_sym)
    return tbl[n - 1][0][v]
end
```

I tested it with this simple example:

```
grammar:
A -> B C
B -> 'x'
C -> 'y'

string: 'xy'
```

The parse table `tbl` was the following:

```
[[[false, true, false], [false, false, true]],
[[false, false, false], [false, false, false]]]
```

The problem definitely lies in the second part of the algorithm - substrings of length larger than 1. The first layer (`tbl[0]`) contains correct values.

Help much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem lies in the translation from the 1-based arrays in the pseudocode to the 0-based arrays in your code.
It becomes obvious when you look at the first indices in the condition `tbl[p][s][b] and tbl[l-p][s+p][c]` in the very first run of the loop. The pseudocode checks `tbl[1] and tbl[1]` and your code checks `tbl[0] and tbl[1]`.

I think you have to make the 0-based correction when you access the array and not in the ranges for `l` and `p`. Otherwise the calculations with the indices are wrong.
This should work:

```
 (2..n).each do |l|
    (0...n - l + 1).each do |s|
      (1..l - 1).each do |p|
        grammar.rules.each do |rule|
          next unless rule.rhs.size == 2
          a = grammar.nonterminals.index(rule.lhs)
          b = grammar.nonterminals.index(rule.rhs[0])
          c = grammar.nonterminals.index(rule.rhs[1])
          if tbl[p - 1][s][b] and tbl[l - p - 1][s + p][c]
            tbl[l - 1][s][a] = true
          end
        end
      end
    end
  end
```